# ggplot > svg file on mac os

Tags: r, svg, ggplot2

I am having a weird problem with exporting ggplots as svg files on my Mac. Interestingly, writing the EXACT code for .pdf will work, tiffs will work too.

these do not work -

```
    AggregateWI2 = summarySE(AggregateWI1, measurevar="WI", groupvars=c("Cond","Iso","within"))
      ggplot(AggregateWI2, aes(x=Cond, y=WI, group=within)) +
geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity", fill="#999999", colour="black") +
facet_grid(Iso ~ ., labeller=iso_labeller) + theme(strip.text.y = element_text(size=18, face="italic"                                                                                                                                           )) + 
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=WI-se, ymax=WI+se), 
              width=.2, position=position_dodge(.9)) +
scale_x_discrete(name="Surgical Condition") + 
scale_y_continuous(name="Water Intake (ml)") + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=18),
    axis.text.y=element_text(size=18),
    axis.title.x=element_text(size=22),
    axis.title.y=element_text(size=22),
    strip.text.y=element_text(size=18))

    ggsave("waterintake.svg")
```

this does work -

```
`pdf("EEstudy2.pdf")
ggplot(height = 100, width = 100, EEdata1, aes(x = COND, y = EE)) + geom_bar(position = position_dodge(), 
stat = "identity", fill = "#999999", colour = "black", aes(width=0.4)) + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = EE - se, ymax = EE + se), width = 0.15, position = position_dodge(0.9)) + 
scale_x_discrete(name = "Isoflurane") + scale_y_continuous(name = "Emetic Episodes") +
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=18),
    axis.text.y=element_text(size=18),
    axis.title.x=element_text(size=22),
    axis.title.y=element_text(size=22),
    strip.text.y=element_text(size=18))
    dev.off()
```

this also doesn't work -

```
svg(file = "boxplotFG.svg", width = 7, height = 7)
ggplot(FGdata, aes(Cond, DMN_NTS))+geom_boxplot()  +xlab("Surgical Condition") + ylab("Gray Level DMN:NTS") + geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(w=0.1, h=0.1), size=3)+ theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=18),
    axis.text.y=element_text(size=18),
    axis.title.x=element_text(size=22),
    axis.title.y=element_text(size=22),
    strip.text.y=element_text(size=18))
dev.off()
```

Comment: Doesn't work how? What are the symptoms?

Comment: What's the issue facing? How doesn't it work?

Comment: Sometimes I get some type of "quartz error" and otherwise it will run but not create any svg file. I've tried searching the entire computer for said file.